# Collecting euro coins of European microstates

Tags: money, vatican-city, monaco, andorra, san-marino

I just got into EURO coins collecting again. The normal coins are pretty easy to get in normal life. But there are 4 European microstates (Andorra, Monaco, San Marino, Vatican City) where there are no coins in circulation. I was wondering if/where one could buy them in the respective countries?

Comment: You can buy them online without leaving your house.

Comment: Of course... But I would have liked to buy them as souvenirs from the respective countries and give me another reason to visit them...

Comment: IIRC the Vatican post office sells coins as well.

Comment: Book a hotel in Monaco. Buy a coin of Monaco and mail it to the hotel. Go To the hotel in Monaco. Visit sights of Monaco. Pick up coin and take it home as souvenir.